# How to retrieve only those elements of list which matches user input?

Tags: python, string, arraylist, lda, lsa

i need to take input from user and only that group of words should return to me where the input string occurs. For example if i search for people then only those group of words where people appears should be retrieved as output.

here is my sample output:

```
 [(0, '0.897*"allah" + 0.120*"indeed" + 0.117*"lord" + 0.110*"said" + 0.101*"people" + 0.093*"upon" + 0.083*"shall" + 0.082*"unto" + 0.072*"believe" + 0.070*"earth"'), (1, '0.495*"lord" + 0.398*"said" + -0.377*"allah" + 0.252*"shall" + 0.241*"people" + 0.236*"unto" + 0.195*"indeed" + 0.131*"upon" + 0.117*"come" + 0.109*"thou"'), (2, '-0.682*"lord" + 0.497*"shall" + 0.350*"unto" + 0.125*"thee" + 0.125*"thou" + -0.098*"indeed" + -0.092*"said" + 0.092*"come" + 0.091*"people" + 0.080*"truth"'), (3, '-0.615*"shall" + 0.520*"people" + -0.395*"lord" + 0.259*"said" + 0.227*"indeed" + 0.103*"would" + 0.081*"sent" + 0.078*"among" + -0.059*"deeds" + -0.053*"good"'), (4, '0.675*"unto" + -0.425*"shall" + -0.335*"indeed"  + 0.214*"thou" + 0.180*"thee" + 0.161*"lord" + -0.105*"said" + 0.099*"hath" + -0.075*"upon"'), (5, '-0.760*"said" + 0.356*"indeed" + 0.261*"upon" + 0.157*"would" + -0.130*"shall" + 0.109*"earth" + -0.108*"allah" + 0.105*"lord" + 0.100*"truth" + 0.096*"good"')
```

Here is my expected output:

```
 [(0, '0.897*"allah" + 0.120*"indeed" + 0.117*"lord" + 0.110*"said" + 0.101*"people" + 0.093*"upon" + 0.083*"shall" + 0.082*"unto" + 0.072*"believe" + 0.070*"earth"'), (1, '0.495*"lord" + 0.398*"said" + -0.377*"allah" + 0.252*"shall" + 0.241*"people" + 0.236*"unto" + 0.195*"indeed" + 0.131*"upon" + 0.117*"come" + 0.109*"thou"'), (2, '-0.682*"lord" + 0.497*"shall" + 0.350*"unto" + 0.125*"thee" + 0.125*"thou" + -0.098*"indeed" + -0.092*"said" + 0.092*"come" + 0.091*"people" + 0.080*"truth"'), (3, '-0.615*"shall" + 0.520*"people" + -0.395*"lord" + 0.259*"said" + 0.227*"indeed" + 0.103*"would" + 0.081*"sent" + 0.078*"among" + -0.059*"deeds" + -0.053*"good"')]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: You should really pass `formatted=False` to `model.show_topics`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use a function with two parameter , one is your desired string and
>   second is your list :

Data is :

```
data=[(0,
  '0.897*"allah" + 0.120*"indeed" + 0.117*"lord" + 0.110*"said" + 0.101*"people" + 0.093*"upon" + 0.083*"shall" + 0.082*"unto" + 0.072*"believe" + 0.070*"earth"'),
 (1,
  '0.495*"lord" + 0.398*"said" + -0.377*"allah" + 0.252*"shall" + 0.241*"people" + 0.236*"unto" + 0.195*"indeed" + 0.131*"upon" + 0.117*"come" + 0.109*"thou"'),
 (2,
  '-0.682*"lord" + 0.497*"shall" + 0.350*"unto" + 0.125*"thee" + 0.125*"thou" + -0.098*"indeed" + -0.092*"said" + 0.092*"come" + 0.091*"people" + 0.080*"truth"'),
 (3,
  '-0.615*"shall" + 0.520*"people" + -0.395*"lord" + 0.259*"said" + 0.227*"indeed" + 0.103*"would" + 0.081*"sent" + 0.078*"among" + -0.059*"deeds" + -0.053*"good"'),
 (4,
  '0.675*"unto" + -0.425*"shall" + -0.335*"indeed"  + 0.214*"thou" + 0.180*"thee" + 0.161*"lord" + -0.105*"said" + 0.099*"hath" + -0.075*"upon"'),
 (5,
  '-0.760*"said" + 0.356*"indeed" + 0.261*"upon" + 0.157*"would" + -0.130*"shall" + 0.109*"earth" + -0.108*"allah" + 0.105*"lord" + 0.100*"truth" + 0.096*"good"')]
```

> Detailed solution :

```
def search_strin(stri,list_1):
    final_list=[]
    for tup in list_1:
        for item in tup:
            if isinstance(item,str):
                if stri in item:
                    final_list.append(tup)

    return final_list

print(search_strin('people',data))
```

output:

Its returning only those group which have 'people' in string.

```
[(0, '0.897*"allah" + 0.120*"indeed" + 0.117*"lord" + 0.110*"said" + 0.101*"people" + 0.093*"upon" + 0.083*"shall" + 0.082*"unto" + 0.072*"believe" + 0.070*"earth"'), (1, '0.495*"lord" + 0.398*"said" + -0.377*"allah" + 0.252*"shall" + 0.241*"people" + 0.236*"unto" + 0.195*"indeed" + 0.131*"upon" + 0.117*"come" + 0.109*"thou"'), (2, '-0.682*"lord" + 0.497*"shall" + 0.350*"unto" + 0.125*"thee" + 0.125*"thou" + -0.098*"indeed" + -0.092*"said" + 0.092*"come" + 0.091*"people" + 0.080*"truth"'), (3, '-0.615*"shall" + 0.520*"people" + -0.395*"lord" + 0.259*"said" + 0.227*"indeed" + 0.103*"would" + 0.081*"sent" + 0.078*"among" + -0.059*"deeds" + -0.053*"good"')]
```

> Just for fun one line solution if you want to try:

```
search='people'

print([tup for tup in data for item in tup if isinstance(item,str) if search in item])
```

As you commented you are getting empty list , You should check that you are passing correct list. You can check here [live running code :](https://repl.it/@aadi1111/test1)

Comment: it is giving me an empty list.

Comment: @Nisa pass the correct list. Paste the full code in pastebin.

Comment: @Nisa Here you go check live running code here :

https://repl.it/@aadi1111/test1

Comment: it is not giving anything..i checked.

Comment: @Nisa have you checked this link and click on run ? repl.it/@aadi1111/test1 
Just click on that link and then click on run button , see the output

Comment: @Nisa have you run via that link ?

Comment: it worked ..thank you.